# Material solid color despite uv image texture

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

[image]

I have uv unwrapped my texture. It is assigned. The image is set to repeat and it has a texture coordinate node, as well as a mapping node, attached.
No matter what I do it only shows up as a solid color, even in renders. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: As you describe it you seem to have done nothing wrong, so it's hard to tell the exact problem. Could you provide the blend file, at least that object where the texture should be? [Upload your file here](https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eD0j580M" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eD0j580M/)                                                                                     this is the .blend file in question